# Visual Studio Warning Rule not warn on variable not used

Tags: .net, compiler-warnings

When I declare a variable and init by simple assignment,I've got a warning as expected

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = 1;
    }
```

But if I changed assignment by a function call, **NO WARNING** at all

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = func();
    }

    static string  func()
    {
        return "Good";
    }
```

In the second example, variable a is never used, my question is:

Why Visual Studio **DOES NOT** generate a warning? I think it's a potential issue on this code segment.

Comment: If you're just after more/better warnings, various tools (one example would be SonarLint) will generate several warnings for your second sample including the one you're asking about.

Comment: As to the "why", the second form allows you to set a breakpoint on the closing brace of `Main` and, upon hitting the breakpoint, to see the value returned by `func` (via `a`). The first example is far less useful in this regard because the assigned value was generated locally in the first place.

Comment: Agree mostly, I think none will explain why it is, expcept the designer/author.

Comment: I would like to know the stratege/pinciple/purpose from either the author or IDE warning designers.